# data-val-date attribute added to dateTimePicker even without ValidationAttribute in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I emit a datetimepicker with this line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Event.EventStart)
```

My editor template is like this:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}",
  Model.HasValue ? Model : null), new { @class = "dateTimePicker" })
```

and that will result in the following html:

```
<input type="text" value="2013-10-26 00:00" name="Event.EventStart"
  id="Event_EventStart" data-val-required="The Startdatum field is required."
  data-val-date="The field Startdatum must be a date." data-val="true"
  class="dateTimePicker hasDatepicker input-validation-error">
```

That is also the case if I do not have a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Event.EventStart)` line.

There is nothing in my code that should enable validation for the property EventStart.

In my model it only looks like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Startdatum")]
public DateTime EventStart { get; set; }
```

It seems like jquery ui (most suspect) is adding validation for *dates* to my dateTimePicker.

Why?

Or is the presence of the data-val-date attribute also triggering *datetime* validation?

The validation fails:

> The field Startdatum must be a date.

It would be nice to either be able to disable the validation or add validation for *datetimes* instead of dates.
Is there some way to actually have the responsibility to add validation myself with data annotations as I do usually (with other datatypes)?

Comment: Its because your property `EventStart` is `DateTime` so it will add the `data-val-required` attribute (because `DateTime` must have a value). If its `DateTime?` (nullable) then the data attribute wont be included (note @model is dynamic so its evaluated at runtime)

Comment: data-val-required is ok, but whats the deal with data-val-date?

Comment: Well its a date so the value needs to be a date otherwise the `DefaultModelBinder` cant bind it. The html helper adds the `data-` attributes based the property type (and any other attributes applied to the property), not jquery ui. Why does _"The validation fails"_?

Comment: I have added the validation message to my question.

Comment: You mentioned jquery ui so I assume you need to set the date format to match your format (the default is "mm/dd/yy") so something like `$(".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });` [Refer documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)